# Which scripture/s describe 15 faced to 21 faced Rudraaksha-s?

Tags: scripture, tantra, rudraksha

The Rudraaksha Jaabaalopanishad describes the lord and merits of wearing 1 faced to 14 faced Rudraakshas. The Shiva Puraan (Vidyeswara Samhitaa) goes no further.

The Shrimad Devi Bhaagvatam mentions the creation of 38 types of Rudraaksha (10+12+16) but it is not specifically stated that these are differentiated on the basis of faces. The suggested differences are more about the colour of the bead. At any rate it does not describe Rudraakshas with more faces than 14.

I have never read the Kaatyaayani Tantra (as no translation or even printed Sanskrit version seems to be available) but [this product page](https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/k/indrakshi-mala) seems to suggest that some details may be available there.

Is there any description of the properties of Rudraakshas with 15 or more faces in any scriptures?

Comment: [This](https://archive.org/details/InternationalJournalOfResearchVol-1Issue-5June2014/Mythological%20and%20Spiritual%20review%20on%20Elaeocarpus%20ganitrus%20and%20assessment%20of%20scientific%20facts%20for%20its%20medicinal%20uses%20-%20Prabha%20Rashmi%2C%20Kaur%20Amrinder/page/n9/mode/2up) article states upto 19 mukha but doesn't explain its source.

Comment: @Proxy Thanks for trying. This is not what I'm looking for. There are innumerable such tracts and webpages describing the higher faced rudrakshas on the websites of rudraksha vendors. I'm looking for a scriptural source.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://igldelhi.com/pdf/rudraksha-benefits-and-uses.pdf) is a pdf that describes the properties and description.

[Another](https://shrikrishnagita.wordpress.com/category/rudraksha/) good read is here, which tells about Rudraksha more.

But, as far as I find, except Rudraaksha Jaabaalopanishad and Shiva Purana, there is no other mention of details about their importance and properties.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. This is not what I'm looking for.